# Setting Physical options for existing tables

Tags: ddl, greenplum

How do I set following Physical options for existing Greenplum tables using sql-script:

```
with(
    appendonly = true,
    orientation = column,
    compresstype = zstd,
    compresslevel = 1
) distributed replicated
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Greenplum doesn't support altering storage types/characteristics for the existing tables. Would have to recreate the table. This enhancement is already tracked via https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/issues/5300. Please feel free to provide insight into your use-case on that GitHub issue.

Distribution of the table though can be changed via ALTER TABLE command for example

```
-- hash distributed table
CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b int) distributed by (a); 

-- alter to convert it to replicated
ALTER TABLE foo set distributed replicated;
```